# sum selected from html select

Tags: javascript, select

Tried several ways, lot of research (maybe I miss something but can't get it done) so, I was wonder if I can sum selected values of a html select

this is my code

```
<select id="m4r1InfoMrP" name="m4r1InfoMrP">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
 <option value="8">8</option>
</select>
```

And the other one

```
<select id="m4r1InfoMrS" name="m4r1InfoMrS" >
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
 <option value="8">8</option>
</select>
```

my JS code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var m4r1InfoMrP = document.getElementById( "m4r1InfoMrP" ),
    m4r1InfoMrPValue = m4r1InfoMrP.value;

 var m4r1InfoMrS = document.getElementById( "m4r1InfoMrS" ),
  m4r1InfoMrSValue = m4r1InfoMrS.value;

 var sum = 0;
 var a = m4r1InfoMrPValue;
 var b = m4r1InfoMrSValue;

 sum = a + b;
 document.getElementById("m4r1InfoMrPS").value = sum;
</script>
```

what I'm looking for is to sum the selected values and show it on m4r1InfoMrPS

thanks in advance

Comment: Where is "m4r1InfoMrPS"? And yes, this can be done, but as written, this script is going to run immediately, and the value will never change even if a user changes either of the selects. You need to look into adding event handlers.

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

Comment: Only one value at a time can be selected unless you add the `multiple` attribute/property to the select, e.g. `<select multiple="multiple">`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `change` event for each `<select>` element. Also, you need to convert to number for addition as below.

```js
var m4r1InfoMrP = document.getElementById("m4r1InfoMrP"),
  m4r1InfoMrPValue = m4r1InfoMrP.value;
var m4r1InfoMrS = document.getElementById("m4r1InfoMrS"),
  m4r1InfoMrSValue = m4r1InfoMrS.value;

m4r1InfoMrP.onchange = () => calculate();
m4r1InfoMrS.onchange = () => calculate();

function calculate() {
  m4r1InfoMrPValue = m4r1InfoMrP.value;
  m4r1InfoMrSValue = m4r1InfoMrS.value;

  var sum = 0;
  var a = +m4r1InfoMrPValue;
  var b = +m4r1InfoMrSValue;

  sum = a + b;
  document.getElementById("m4r1InfoMrPS").value = sum;
}

calculate()
```

```html
<select id="m4r1InfoMrP" name="m4r1InfoMrP">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
</select>

<select id="m4r1InfoMrS" name="m4r1InfoMrS">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
</select>

<input id="m4r1InfoMrPS" />
```

Comment: Consider using [`Number`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Function_syntax) or [`parseFloat`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead of the [unary `+`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) for clarity. Prefer [`addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) over `.onchange`. Also, consider using [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation).